# Where and how to change session user object after signing in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I have weird problem and I don't know where the problem is. I use [next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org/) library to make authentication system in my `Next.js` app.

Everything is OK - I can sign in by checking if there is account in `google firebase` with submitted credentials, `session` is being created properly, but when the `authorize` callback is initialized I pass data received from `google firestore` after correct sign in. User object contains whole data and it's passed forward.

Then, when I want to read data from `session`, some data I passed before is missing.

Code:

/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth.js]

```js
export default (req, res) => 
    NextAuth(req, res, {
        providers: [
            Providers.Credentials({
                name: 'Credentials',
                credentials: {
                    phone: { label: "Phone number", type: "text" },
                    password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
                },
                authorize: async (loginData) => {
                    const { csrfToken, phone, password } = loginData;
                    
                    //  checking if there is account with these credentials
                    let res = await login({
                        phone, 
                        password: sha1(md5(password)).toString()
                    })

                    //  200 = OK
                    if(res.status == 200){
                        //  collect account data
                        const user = {
                            phone,
                            ...res.data.info
                        }

                        //  user object is created correctly, whole data is stored there
                        console.log('received account data from firestore', user)
                        return Promise.resolve(user);
                    }
                    else {
                        //  wrong credentials
                        return Promise.resolve(null);
                    }
                }
            })
        ],
        callbacks: {
            session: async (session, user) => {
                console.log('data passed to object when signed in', user)
                //  user object there doesn't have all data passed before
                return Promise.resolve(session)
            }
        },
        debug: false
    })
```

Console logged objects:

```
received account data from firestore 
{
  phone: '123123123',
  id: 'w2zh88BZzSv5BJeXZeZX',
  email: 'jan@gmail.com',
  name: 'Jan',
  surname: 'Kowalski'
}
```

```
data passed to object when signed in 
{
  name: 'Jan',
  email: 'jan@gmail.com',
  iat: 1603900133,
  exp: 1606492133
}
```

The best thing is, the object (above) always has the same properties. I can pass any object in `authorize` callback, but in `session`, `user` object always has "name, email, iat, exp" ALWAYS. The only thing that changes are values of these two properties in object (name, email). (rest properties - "phone, id, surname" - are missing).

Below there is console logged `session` object in any react component:

```
import {
    signIn, 
    signOut,
    useSession
} from 'next-auth/client'

const [ session, loading ] = useSession();
console.log(session)
```

[Photo of console logged session object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbhO9.png)

What can I do? Do I have to receive data from `firestore` separately in `session` callback? Is the server-side rendering of `Next.js` causing the problem?

Comment: Had the same issue, some additional comments on this problem here: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/312#issuecomment-718786847

Answer (score 82):

I resolved that problem by myself.
This issue thread helped me a lot!
https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/764

Below is the explanation:

```
callbacks: {
    jwt: async (token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) => {
        //  "user" parameter is the object received from "authorize"
        //  "token" is being send below to "session" callback...
        //  ...so we set "user" param of "token" to object from "authorize"...
        //  ...and return it...
        user && (token.user = user);
        return Promise.resolve(token)   // ...here
    },
    session: async (session, user, sessionToken) => {
        //  "session" is current session object
        //  below we set "user" param of "session" to value received from "jwt" callback
        session.user = user.user;
        return Promise.resolve(session)
    }
}
```

## EDIT: Due to NextAuth update to v4

###### Version 4 of NextAuth brings some changes to callbacks shown above. Now there is only one argument assigned to `jwt` and `session` functions. However, you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) it to separate variables. Rest of the code stays the same as before.

https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback
https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#session-callback

```js
// api/auth/[...nextauth].js

...
callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
        user && (token.user = user)
        return token
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
        session.user = token.user
        return session
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a good lead. These days the signature looks more like, `session: async (session, user) => {`. Also, since you're using `async` you can just return `session`, you don't need to use `Promise.resolve`.

Comment: this solved my issue too, thanks for the edit for v4.

Comment: The property to be attached to token and session objects has to be "user" only. I wasted a lot of time trying to name it something else. Finally made it works with this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Using federated identity (cognito -> okta), the attribute data I needed was in the `profile` property of the `jwt` function argument i.e. `jwt: async({ token, profile, user }) => { ... }`

Comment: I've been struggling with this for username.  Thanks so much for sharing your solution!

Comment: How did you persist the user field on the session? If the session callback runs again, the new field is not included.

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling with this for while. They should probably add this to the Docs

Comment: Thank you. You just saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and it turned out to be the functions in the Adapter that caused the problem. In my case, I wanted to use v4 of next-auth, and I wanted to use DynamoDB. As there is no official v4 adapter for Dynamo, I had to write my own, basing it on the [publicly available v3 adapter](https://github.com/nextauthjs/adapters/blob/main/packages/dynamodb/src/index.ts).

One of the functions [you have to provide when creating your own adapter](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/creating-a-database-adapter) is:

```
async updateUser(user) {
  // use ddb client to update the user record
  // client returns `data`
  return { ...user, ...data.Attributes }
}
```

It turns out that the data in `data.Attributes` is what gets passed to your `jwt()` [callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback) as `user`. This seems to be different to the v3 implementation.

Therefore in my case I had to structure the dynamodb adapter's `updateUser()` function to instruct the client to return ALL_NEW and not merely UPDATED_NEW (which is what the v3 adapter does).

My complete `updateUser()` function is as follows - bear in mind that at this point, I used the [recommended dynamodb table structure](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/dynamodb) (which I don't necessarily agree with, especially in my use case, but that's another story)

```
async updateUser(user) {
    const now = new Date()
    const data = await client.update({
        TableName: tableName,
        Key: {
            pk: `USER#${user.id}`,
            sk: `USER#${user.id}`,
        },
        UpdateExpression:
            "set #emailVerified = :emailVerified, #updatedAt = :updatedAt",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#emailVerified": "emailVerified",
            "#updatedAt": "updatedAt",
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":emailVerified": user.emailVerified?.toISOString() ?? null,
            ":updatedAt": now.toISOString(),
        },
        ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
    }).promise()
    
    return { ...user, ...data.Attributes }
},
```

As a result, I see `user` fully populated in the `jwt()` callback:

```
callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
        console.debug("callback jwt user:", user)
        user && (token.user = user)
        return token
    },
```

The debug output is the complete record for the user from DynamoDB, and can be used as described in @MateuszWawrzynski's answer.